# Auto-complete and some technical in web application

Tags: database, search, web-applications, autocomplete

I have some problems still do not understand and I need help.

In some web application like Facebook, when I type a word to find my friends or places, apps..., a suggestion list appear for me. I can traverse and choose one of them.

So I want to ask something:

1. Best or good tool, language or something like that to do this? I think it's jQuery. More options for me?
2. Which is a list item in the suggestion list called?
3. Where did these things from? I means: how can I create or take them? From database directly?

Comment: what language are you looking to do this in ?

Answer (score 0):

The answers are:

1. You can use jQuery coupled with a server side language that retrieve the data
2. Usually it's called suggestion list. These function is Google is called Google suggest
3. The data are retrieved from the database

Comment: Thanks so much! But I want to ask you for the third question. I think if all list item in suggestion list are retrieved from database, it's not efficient. Many requests at a time or while typing, suggestion list will change many times, access and retrieve from database consume high cost.

Comment: Please reply me later if you have free time. :)

Comment: @Kant The basic technique is this but obviously for an efficient application you should use a caching system like memcached.